# Webkit/webkit2 Browser

Tags: web, safari, webkit, webkit2

Blink (Chromium) was foked from webkit. and they are separated two or three years ago.

Seems there are many browsers using chromium engine. By the way is there any other browser powered by webkit/webkit2 except safari?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Web browser (package name epiphany or epiphany-browser) is the official **GNOME** web browser.

**Luakit** has been ported to **WebKit2**.  **Midori** can be built with WebKit2 but by default it is built with WebKit1.

The surf browser at **surf.suckless.org** is a minimalist browser which uses **WebKit2**.